# How to add a nested column to a DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe `df` with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- city_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- person: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

What I want to do is add a nested column, say `car_brand` to my `person` structure. How would I do it?

The expected final schema would look like this:

```
root
 |-- city_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- person: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- car_brand: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can unpack the struct and add it to a new one, including the new column at the same time. For example, adding "bmw" to all persons in the dataframe be done like this:

```
df.withColumn("person", struct($"person.*", lit("bmw").as("car_brand")))
```

Comment: This solution does not work with three level nested fields. How can we add  `nested_col` field here?                  
 root 
 |-- city_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- person: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
           |-- nested_col: string (nullable = true)

Comment: @Sindhu If I understand correctly you want to add the `nested_col` to the person struct? You can do this by using the method in the answer, just change`lit("bmw")` to `$"nested_col"`.

Comment: No, Actually I want to add a column when there is one more level of nesting per say `name`  here, assuming `name` is struct here just like `person`.

Comment: @Sindhu If there isn't too many columns then you could do something like follows: `withColumn("person", struct($"person.age", struct($"person.name", $"nested_col").as("name)))`. However, this will change a bit depending on the type of the column (here your name column is a string, not a struct). If you want a more detailed answer for your use case, I would recommend asking a new question on the site with more information (you can leave the link in a comment here).

Answer (score 2):

Adding a new nested column within person:

```
df = df.withColumn(
        "person",
        struct(
            $"person.*",
            struct(
                lit("value_1").as("person_field_1"),
                lit("value_2").as("person_field_2"),
            ).as("nested_column_within_person")
       )
    )
```

Final schema :

```
root
 |-- city_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- person: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- nested_column_within_person: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- person_field_1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- person_field_2: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Is there any syntax changed in the recent versions?  i'm getting SyntaxError: invalid  syntax for 
cdc_df.withColumn("AuditPayload", struct( lit("value_1").as("person_field_1"),lit("value_2").as("person_field_2"),).as("nested_column_within_person")))

Answer (score 1):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
dF = dF.withColumn(
        "person",
   func.struct(
            "person.age",
                func.struct(
                            "person.name",
                            func.lit(None).alias("NestedCol_Name")
                    ).alias("name")
       )
       )
O/P Schema:-
root
 |-- city_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- person: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- age: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- NestedCol_Name: null (nullable = true)
```

Comment: this solution will help to add the nested column at more than one level and as per above example it will add  a nested column i.e. ('NestedCol_Name')  inside name column which we already have. Hope it answers @Sindhu's question

Answer (score 1):

The function [withField](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#withField-java.lang.String-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-) is available starting Spark 3.1. As per the doc, "it can be used to add/replace a nested field in `StructType` by name".

In this case, it can be used as follows: -

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions

df.withColumn("person", functions.col("person").withField("car_brand", functions.col("some car brand here")))
```