# Change value of nested column in DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have dataframe with two level nested fields

```
 root
 |-- request: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- dummyID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- fooID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- barID: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to update the value of `fooId` column here. I was able to update value for the first level for example `dummyID` column here using this question as reference [How to add a nested column to a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49046886/how-to-add-a-nested-column-to-a-dataframe)

Input data:

```
{
    "request": {
        "dummyID": "test_id",
        "data": {
            "fooID": "abc",
            "barID": "1485351"
        }
    }
}
```

output data:

```
{
    "request": {
        "dummyID": "test_id",
        "data": {
            "fooID": "def",
            "barID": "1485351"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do it using Scala?

Comment: is this only one json string ? or you have a lot of data like that. I guess spark won't be fruitful for small data. and please update how you are converting the json to dataframe

Comment: Yes, just one json string here.Unfortunately, I have to use spark here.  Data ouput also needs to be in json as well. dataframe conversion above is just `printSchema()`                                                          testDf = sparkSession.read.json("fileLoc")
    testDf.printSchema()

Comment: I am not going to answer it as it is inefficient use of spark but you can do `df.withColumn("request", struct(struct(lit("def").as("fooID"), col("request.data.barID").as("barID")).as("data"), col("request.dummyID").as("dummyID")))` good luck :)

Answer (score 8):

Here is a generic solution to this problem that makes it possible to update any number of nested values, at any level, based on an arbitrary function applied in a recursive traversal:

```scala
def mutate(df: DataFrame, fn: Column => Column): DataFrame = {
  // Get a projection with fields mutated by `fn` and select it
  // out of the original frame with the schema reassigned to the original
  // frame (explained later)
  df.sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.select(traverse(df.schema, fn):_*).rdd, df.schema)
}

def traverse(schema: StructType, fn: Column => Column, path: String = ""): Array[Column] = {
  schema.fields.map(f => {
    f.dataType match {
      case s: StructType => struct(traverse(s, fn, path + f.name + "."): _*)
      case _ => fn(col(path + f.name))
    }
  })
}
```

This is effectively equivalent to the usual "just redefine the whole struct as a projection" solutions, but it automates re-nesting fields with the original structure AND preserves nullability/metadata (which are lost when you redefine the structs manually).  Annoyingly, preserving those properties isn't possible while creating the projection (afaict) so the code above redefines the schema manually.

An example application:

```scala
case class Organ(name: String, count: Int)
case class Disease(id: Int, name: String, organ: Organ)
case class Drug(id: Int, name: String, alt: Array[String])

val df = Seq(
  (1, Drug(1, "drug1", Array("x", "y")), Disease(1, "disease1", Organ("heart", 2))),
  (2, Drug(2, "drug2", Array("a")), Disease(2, "disease2", Organ("eye", 3)))
).toDF("id", "drug", "disease")

df.show(false)

+---+------------------+-------------------------+
|id |drug              |disease                  |
+---+------------------+-------------------------+
|1  |[1, drug1, [x, y]]|[1, disease1, [heart, 2]]|
|2  |[2, drug2, [a]]   |[2, disease2, [eye, 3]]  |
+---+------------------+-------------------------+

// Update the integer field ("count") at the lowest level:
val df2 = mutate(df, c => if (c.toString == "disease.organ.count") c - 1 else c)
df2.show(false)

+---+------------------+-------------------------+
|id |drug              |disease                  |
+---+------------------+-------------------------+
|1  |[1, drug1, [x, y]]|[1, disease1, [heart, 1]]|
|2  |[2, drug2, [a]]   |[2, disease2, [eye, 2]]  |
+---+------------------+-------------------------+

// This will NOT necessarily be equal unless the metadata and nullability
// of all fields is preserved (as the code above does)
assertResult(df.schema.toString)(df2.schema.toString)
```

A limitation of this is that it cannot add new fields, only update existing ones (though the map can be changed into a flatMap and the function to return Array[Column] for that, if you don't care about preserving nullability/metadata).

Additionally, here is a more generic version for Dataset[T]:

```scala
case class Record(id: Int, drug: Drug, disease: Disease)

def mutateDS[T](df: Dataset[T], fn: Column => Column)(implicit enc: Encoder[T]): Dataset[T] = {
  df.sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.select(traverse(df.schema, fn):_*).rdd, enc.schema).as[T]
}

// To call as typed dataset:
val fn: Column => Column = c => if (c.toString == "disease.organ.count") c - 1 else c
mutateDS(df.as[Record], fn).show(false)

// To call as untyped dataset:
implicit val encoder: ExpressionEncoder[Row] = RowEncoder(df.schema) // This is necessary regardless of sparkSession.implicits._ imports
mutateDS(df, fn).show(false)
```

Comment: It was really helpful but I am getting Java heap out of memory error on this  while converting rdd to df .Could you please help me with it ?  df.sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.select(traverse(df.schema, fn):_*).rdd, df.schema)

Comment: Can anybody translate first solution to Java

Comment: how to change the datatype of field instead of value?

Comment: How could you achieve this in python? Thank you

Comment: @Eric Czech do you have pyspark version of this?

Answer (score 1):

One way, although cumbersome is to fully unpack and recreate the column by explicitly referencing each element of the original struct.

```
dataFrame.withColumn("person", 
    struct(
        col("person.age").alias("age),
        struct(
            col("person.name.first").alias("first"),
            lit("some new value").alias("last")).alias("name")))
```