# Replace an existing field within array using spark

Tags: pyspark

I have a field within an array as below.

```
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- cola: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- colb: string (nullable = true)
```

I have done some calculation on colb using myudf which is within the array col2.

`myDF=myDF.withColumn(colb, myudf(colb))`

When I use withColumn, it creates a new column but I want to replace the existing column with new value. Can anyone suggest how this can be done.

```
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- cola: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- colb: string (nullable = true)
 |-- colb: array (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change value of nested column in DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50123771/change-value-of-nested-column-in-dataframe)

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not address how to add to an array. Can you please help.