# how to add a column with nested elements to a dataframe from other columns (withColumn)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark dataframe which looks like

```
C C1 C2 C3
1 2  3  4
```

I want to add another nested column, which is going to make that column of the data frame a json, or an object, I'm not even sure of the correct wording for what this is.  It will take the information from other columns of the same row

```
C C1 C2 C3  V
1 2  3  4   {"C:1", "C1:2", "C2:3", "C3:4"}
```

I have tried [How to add a nested column to a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49046886/how-to-add-a-nested-column-to-a-dataframe) but I don't know what the correct syntax in PySpark is, opposed to that question, which is Scala, and that solution looks that will only work for 1 row, I need to do this for hundreds of millions of rows.

I have tried `df2 = df.withColumn("V", struct("V.*", col("C1").as('C1')))` but this gives a mysterious syntax error.

Edit: I would not say that this question is a duplicate of [pyspark convert row to json with nulls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53525470/pyspark-convert-row-to-json-with-nulls) because the solution which was posted by a user here, which solved my problem, is not posted there.

How can I make that nested column `V` from the rest of the columns in the same row?

Comment: `as` is a keyword in Python. Use `alias` - `col("C1").alias('C1')`

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53525701/5858851) what you're looking for?

Comment: @pault this isn't a duplicate, because the solution on that page isn't what I want, User sailesh solved my problem.  His solution doesn't appear on that page.  Also, I eliminate rows with null values.  Null values aren't a concern here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PySpark you can achieve using struct. You don't need an alias.

```
df.withColumn("V", struct(col("C"), col("C1"), col("C2"), col("C3"))
```

If you don't want to hard code the column names you can also do

```
df.withColumn("V", struct(col("*"))
```

Comment: Using this method and then converting to JSON will not work correctly for `null` values.